# displaying the block time on only one card

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar, schedule

[here is the image of block time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR7sI.png)I'm displaying block time based on absence. It is displaying the card in each hour, start time to end time. I want to diplay only one card which covers the entire the block time from start time to end time.

For example the block time is 1pm to 2pm, then it shoud be only one card which covers 1pm to 2pm. It should not diplay each card in each hours.

```html
<div class="border radius-3 p-3 calendar_main" style="border-width: 2px !important;">
  <div class="table-responsive dc-h-fixed booking_table">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Time Slot</th>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let emp of stylist">
            <th *ngIf="!isWeekOff(selectedday,emp.offDays)">{{ emp.name }}</th>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- <th *ngFor="let s of stylist"><img src="../../../assets/img/icons/eye.svg" alt="" width="18"> {{s.name}}</th> -->
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let hr of incTime">
          <td width="150">{{hr}}:00</td>
          <td *ngFor="let s of stylist">
            <div class="d-flex gap-2 overflow-hidden card-outer">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let app of appointments">
                <div [ngClass]="app.status === 'ongoing' ? 'booking_item ongoing_' : app.status === 'upcoming' ? 'booking_item upcoming_' : app.status === 'completed' ? 'booking_item completed_' : app.status === 'cancelled' ? 'booking_item offline_' : app.status === 'noshow' ? 'booking_item noshow_' : app.status === 'reschedule' ? 'booking_item reschedule_' : ''"
                  class="p-2 radius-1" *ngIf="(s.name == app.stylist.name) && (app.time.split(':')[0] == hr) && (currentDate == app.date.slice(0, 10))">
                  <div *ngFor="let service of app.services"><strong>{{service.name}}</strong></div>
                  <div>{{app.time}}</div>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="absence.length > 0">
                <!-- <div class="d-flex gap-2 overflow-hidden card-outer"> -->
                <ng-container *ngFor="let abs of absence">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="(s.name == abs.stylist.name) && (currentDate == abs.startdate.slice(0, 10))">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="hr >= abs.starttime.split(':')[0] && hr <= abs.endtime.split(':')[0]">
                      <div class="p-2 radius-1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);">
                        <strong>{{abs.reason}}</strong>
                        <div>{{abs.starttime}} to {{abs.endtime}}</div>
                      </div>
                    </ng-container>
                  </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
                <!-- </div> -->
              </ng-container>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ganesh, Can you share image or elaborate more on this. are you creating calendar? or time slot manager?